# Start an animation exported from 3ds Max in UDK

Tags: animation, udk, 3dsmax, unreal

I made a shape in 3ds Max with one bone and I gave it an animation. I exported it and imported to UDK. When I shoot to that shape, I want my animation to start playing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your object needs to play some animations when something happens for it.

In UDK, to have some animations, you need to make an `AnimTree` and `AnimSet` node for that object (SkeletonMesh).

For Playing animations that aren't usually for loop ( like: dying, reloading weapon, opening a door, ...), you should ensure you have a `AnimNodeSlot` in your AnimTree as below:

[image]

This node should place right after your `BaseNode` and other part of your tree should place next to this node.

Next step go to UnrealScript.

First you should get access to this *AnimNodeSlot* whith its name :

```
var AnimNodeSlot slot;
...
simulated event PostInitAnimTree(SkeletalMeshComponent SkelComp)
{
    super.PostInitAnimTree(SkelComp);
    mySlot = AnimNodeSlot ( Mesh.FindAnimNode('mySlotName')) ;
}
```

And Finally you should select an animation from your *AnimSet* node with its name to play, as follow:

```
mySlot.PlayCustomAnim('YourAnimationName', ... )
```

It's Done. Hope makes sense :)